# Incorrect syntax near the keyword table when I declare a table variable

Tags: sybase

I am using Sybase database ISQL.exe. when I declare a table variable using this clause:

```
declare @tabVar table (fid int, name varchar(10))
```

I got error:
could not execute statement.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'

I don't see where is wrong, could any one help?

Answer (score 4):

It's not correct construction. You can't use table type variable in sybase. For this solution I suggest to use temporary table as below:

```
create table #tabVar 
(
 fid int, 
 name varchar(10)
)
```

Comment: do you mean Sybase doesn't support table variable?

Answer (score 0):

This must be new in Sybase; I am using it now.

`DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE @tabVar (fid int, name varchar(10))`